# Redis Flushall command in Heroku Scheduler (Python/Django Project)

Tags: python, django, heroku

For a Django application, I want Heroku Scheduler to perform the following commands:

- heroku redis:cli
- flushall
- exit (ctrl-c)

I do this myself once a day now in terminal, but it would be a lot easier if I can schedule these commands.

My question is, is it possible to put these commands in a Python script, or do I need to work in another way? Does anyone has experience with this?